# Change in windows height in two different browsers

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, gwt

In my web application, i am using Window.getClientHeight() , to get height of current window. 
But its giving different result in firefox and in IE. Any idea why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: `Gets the height of the browser window's client area excluding the scroll bar.`

Answer (score 0):

Window/Page/Document height is currently subject to vendor (IE/Moz/Apple/...) implementation and does not have a standard and consistent result cross-browser. Thats why you are getting different result in firefox and in IE

Comment: but its giving drastic difference, as i mentioned in above comment. Any workaround for this then?

Answer (score 0):

I used to face this problem and solve it using JSNI methods. For what it's worth here is one possible implementation.

```
  private static native int getHeight() /*-{
        if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight && $doc.body.clientHeight) {
            if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight > $doc.body.clientHeight) {
                return $doc.documentElement.clientHeight;
            } else {
                return $doc.body.clientHeight;
            }
        } else if ($doc.body.clientHeight) {
            return $doc.body.clientHeight;
        } else if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            return $doc.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
  }-*/;
```